# I want to integrate yahoo in my iphone application

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Yahoo API Integration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361290/yahoo-api-integration)

I want to integrate yahoo in my iphone application,how can i integrate yahoo in iphone application and access my account and sending and receiving messages from my friend.how can acheive this.can any one answer my questio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yahoo has an [API](http://developer.yahoo.com/social/sdk/objectivec/) for iOS , the [sample project](https://github.com/yahoo/yos-social-objc) can help you.